# Is there a shortcut for Places->search for files in classic mode?

Tags: 11.04, shortcut-keys, search, gnome

Is there a shortcut for **Places -> Search for Files** on Ubuntu 11.04 (classic)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ubuntu 10.04 there is but it is disabled by default.

Open the *System->Preferences->Keyboard Shortcuts* dialog and find the "Search" action, then set your own shortcut by click at this action.